# How do I use a regular expression to match strings that don't start with an empty space?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

> I want a regular expression that checks that a string doesn't start with an empty space.

I want to do something like this:

Is the following ValidationExpression right for it?

```
string ValidationExpression = @"/^[^ ]/";

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(GroupName) && !Regex.IsMatch(GroupName, ValidationExpression))
{    
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about `"^\S"`
This will make sure that the first character is not a whitespace character.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use:

```
   if(GroupName.StartsWith(string.Empty)); // where GroupName == any string
```

Comment: Yes - Regular expression is  hammer for this problem. 

or value[0] == '  '

Comment: And unless failing validation is important, one could just .Trim or .TrimStart and preemptively correct the issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^\s+");
```

You can check with

```
  Match m1 = rx.Match("   ");  //m1.Success should be true
  Match m2 = rx.Match("qwerty   ");  //m2.Success should be false
```

Comment: \s means white-space, use \S that means none white-space

Comment: @zwi: In the context of the program, I'm not sure it matters much which one you use, but well spotted nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe :

```
/^[^ ]/
```

And, for a couple of notes about that :

- The first `^` means "*string starts with*"
- The `[^ ]` means "*one character that is not a space*"
- And the `//` are regex delimiter -- not sure if they are required in C#, though.

Comment: Hey hi Pascal i have updated my question : 

so is the value i am giving to 
 string ValidationExpression = @"/^[^ ]/"; is right

Comment: -1: Not the .NET tag, .NET Regex's don't have special delimiters. Also you're only detecting spaces, not tabs or other whitespace.